# Android App started crashing in Android M only

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Only in Android M I am seeing the below crash when displaying the images one by one using view pager. In all the older Android's it is working fine, Any clue on what we are missing?

```
10-22 17:06:59.798   372   372 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8
10-22 17:06:59.846   372   372 F DEBUG   :     r0 00000000  r1 b41a340c  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
10-22 17:06:59.846   372   372 F DEBUG   :     r4 00000000  r5 00000000  r6 701dfdcc  r7 00000000
10-22 17:06:59.846   372   372 F DEBUG   :     r8 132b67f0  r9 acc6ff00  sl 13362c70  fp 13840400
10-22 17:06:59.846   372   372 F DEBUG   :     ip b6ee5df0  sp b41a33f8  lr b6e91047  pc b6e91010  cpsr 60070030
10-22 17:06:59.860   372   372 F DEBUG   : 
10-22 17:06:59.860   372   372 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
10-22 17:06:59.860   372   372 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 0008d010  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::Bitmap::getAshmemFd() const+13)
10-22 17:06:59.861   372   372 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0008d043  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
10-22 17:06:59.861   372   372 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 72c2af6d  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x1eb1000)
10-22 17:07:01.904   861  1362 E NativeCrashListener: Exception dealing with report
```

Answer (score 0):

In android 6 you have a new permissions system. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-runtime-permissions .
its not enough to ask for permissions in manifest.